# @ManyToMany Uni Directional Relation Unnecessary Delete

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

What i want if i delete Overlay.java object delete and insert should only occur in OVERLAY and OVERLAY_ACCOUNTS. but overlay delete cause to insert and delete in ACCOUNT and ACCOUNT_POSITONS also
**Overlay.java**

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "OVERLAY_ACCOUNTS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "overlay_id", referencedColumnName = "overlay_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "account_id", name = "account_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Account> overlayAccounts;
```

**Account.java**

This class have uni directional mapping with Overlay.java so no mapping of Overlay.java is defined in this class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable {
// Other mappings

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "account_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private List<AccountPosition> positions = new ArrayList<AccountPosition>();



}
```

**Create Overlay**

```
public void createOverlay() {

try {
    overlayDao = new OverlayDao();
    overlayDao.beginTransaction();
    overlayDao.save(overlay);
    overlayDao.commit();
}
catch (HibernateException e) {
    Assert.fail("Overlay save failed: " + e.getMessage());
    overlayDao.rollback();
}
finally {
    overlayDao.closeSession();
}

}
```

> Above code cause to execute insert on AccountPosition of Account.java
>   as well below is query executed for AccountPosition **insert into
>   ACCOUNT_POSITIONS** and **Insert Into ACCOUNT**
>
> Same as above Delete Overlay Cause to execute execute delete statement
>   on Account and its sub table AccountPosition

Answer (score 1):

The solution here, would/should be very simple, just do not use `cascade` setting for the `@ManyToMany` mapping. Or at least do not use `CascadeType.ALL`

In this case, cascading setting it is a bit different then `one-to-many` and `many-to-one`. And the reason is in the "hidden" pairing table. This pairing table is representing the `many-to-many` and must be always managed by Hibernate... I.e.: cascade setting is **not** related to that pairing table

*NOTE: well in fact it is not different from `one-to-many` and `many-to-one` ... in all cases cascade is targeting the visible end. just in case of `many-to-many` it skips the pairing table*

Maybe surprisingly, the `cascade` here is not belonging to the pairing table, but to the second end of this relation. Just do **not** use cascade *(at least not for delete)* and all behaviour will be as expected.

Comment: removing Cascade resolved my all problem but i have found another issue, hibernate executing inner join with OVERLAY_ACCOUNT and ACCOUNT while i want it to be left join

Comment: My suggestion here would be to use the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` and if needed eager, use it explicitly in queries. So, all many to many will be handled as separted SELECT (check the batch-size setting as well) and we would not need LEFT JOIN by default. but it is just a suggestion. Anyhow, good that the cascade issue is solve ;)